# ruby hash of arrays that contain arrays

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm learning ruby and am having some trouble working with hashes that contain multi-dimensional arrays.

For example, I'm trying to create a hash with keys that are a city names. Then, inside that city, I want to have an array that contains arrays of data.

It should look something like this:

```
hash = {"chicago" => [["carl","blue"], ["ross", "red"]], "new york" => [ ["linda", "green"], ["john", "purple"], ["chris", "black"]]}
```

How can I make this work, and how can I access/append to the arrays inside of each key?

I've been trying something like:

```
hash["chicago"][].push["new person", "color"]
```

Thanks, I know this is pretty trivial, but I can't seem to wrap my head around in it Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's helpful to break things down into steps. So, we know `hash` is the hash, and `hash['chicago']` is the array of arrays, so from this we can see that we want to push into `hash['chicago']`. This means that the only thing wrong with your code is that you have an extra pair of braces. So we get:

```
hash['chicago'].push ['new person', 'yellow or something']
```

Comment: It can also be handy when learning to recognize that `push` is a method (not something that acts like an array), so `hash['chicago'].push(['new person', 'yellow or something'])` will be the same as above.

Comment: got ya, this is something that's been tripping me up in ruby btw. there's like 3 syntactical ways to do everything and it gets confusing

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, I typically define the hash with a default proc that determines what should happen when a given key is not present in the hash:

```
hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

In this case, the default value is an empty array. Adding new data to the hash is then as simple as:

```
hash["chicago"] << ["carl", "blue"]
```

One caveat - if you're doing lookups, missing values will be represented as an empty array. You can work around this using `fetch` rather than the square bracket notation:

```
hash.fetch("chicago", nil) #=> [["carl", "blue"]]
hash.fetch("new york", nil) #=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way :

```
hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
hash["chicago"].push ["carl","blue"]
hash["chicago"].push ["ross", "red"]
hash
# => {"chicago"=>[["carl", "blue"], ["ross", "red"]]}

hash["new york"].push ["linda", "green"]
hash["new york"].push ["john", "purple"]

hash
# => {"chicago"=>[["carl", "blue"], ["ross", "red"]],
#     "new york"=>[["linda", "green"], ["john", "purple"]]}
```

From [`new {|hash, key| block } → new_hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-new)

> If a *block* is specified, it will be called with the hash object and the key, and should return the default value. It is the block’s responsibility to store the value in the hash if required.

---

> how can I access ?

Use [`Hash#fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) or [`Hash#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) for the same, which suits your need.